# Powering 12 LED tea lights with recycled power adapter?

Tags: led, charger, light, diy

I have 12 tea lights that are each powered by a C2030 3 V battery.

Like many of us I have a box of various chargers and whatnot.

Is this as simple as finding one outputting 3 V and splitting it 12 ways to each of the lights? The have some sort of microcontroller in them, they have timers and are remote controlled.

I’d plug this into a formula if I knew which one to use.

Comment: It seems likely that a common 3V source of edequate current rating would work well. Sometimes things do unexpected things but it seems unlikely in this case.\

Comment: Do check the actual output of the charger/power adapter that you plan on using. Low cost chargers may be unregulated and output more than 3v. Worse case you may need to add a small 3v regulator, (but then if you were to use a small regulator you could likely even use a 5v adapter, [usb like] )

Answer (score 0):

Mostly, yes that's the general idea. But sometimes these lights depend on the internal resistance of the cr2032 batteries instead of having their own resistors, you may need to add a resistor for the typical current draw of the leds. Measure the current with an ammeter or multimeter, and then use ohms law to figure out the resistance needed.

Comment: I have a multimeter, but I’ve only used it to check continuity of relays and heating elements. 

I assume there is a current draw more and I just touch the terminals with no battery in there?

Comment: To check the current draw on a small battery powered device you would need to lift one terminal away from the battery, then connect the leads from a multimeter (in DC current mode) between the lifted terminal and the battery, then switch the device on and measure the current.  (Be sure to test at the highest brightness mode).

Comment: @JohnBell most common cheap multimeters may have a 10 or 20 amp current sense mode. You connect it in line with the device you are measuring the current of.